# iOS: How can I change the app name in the Open-With action sheet in Info.plist?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, info-plist

I am developing a chat app in iOS.

My goal is to process images from other apps including Messages.

So I added the following keys to `Info.plist`:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string></string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Images</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Now I can see my app in the action sheet but the app name has the prefix **Import with**.

How can I replace it with only my app name? (How can I remove **Import with**?).

[image: Activity view controller - Import With prefix in action's name]

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the Action Extension's **Bundle display name** (`CFBundleDisplayName`).

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>[Your App]</string>
```